# #1045 Access Denied - Editing Config.ini file work

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm getting a #1045 Access denied error and I'm not sure what's causing it.

Yesterday I installed WAMP on my computer at work. I switched Apache to run on Port 8080 due to a conflict with IIS7. I logged into phpmyadmin just fine, create a database for a Wordpress site, successfully completed the Wordpress install, and had a lovely day at work.

This morning I'm locked out of my phpmyadmin account. I did not chance the password but left it "root" and [null]. WAMP seems to be running successfully otherwise.

> **#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

After attempting a few tutorials to reset the password without success (the config.ini file, by the way, still showed the password as [null]), I uninstalled everything, reinstalled everything, and everything works. As a test, I logged in and out of phpmyadmin several times. No problem. But when I restarted my computer, the same error happened.

Out of curiosity, I uninstalled, restarted, reinstalled, and set up a password. Restarted the computer, and now I get the below error.

> **#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

Actually, it's the same error just YES or NO depending on whether or not I type something in…but you guys are mad geniuses so you already know that).

Any idea what's causing this? Having to reinstall everything every morning sort of takes the point of a localhost away…

Comment: Do you have more than one MYSQL Server running?

Comment: I did. My god it's fixed. I swear I looked for this earlier and just missed it in the lineup. Uninstalled everything, reinstalled ONLY WAMP, and after several restarts everything seems to be holding up.  Thank you very much for the rescue!